# how to split a string at the end of a regex pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a very biiiiiig string

```
"aijsdif_213 uweobasjdbfajb
ajksdbfaj-sd_bh kjsham
aisj_drieuku*qger ijwel,34jn
iu32iu4h8heuih+_8u5jns.. iuw&^ijk
.
.
.
.iuwh3iuw"
```

I want to split it for every ~1400approx. characters including the line breaks.

I used something like this,

```
Splitter.fixedLength(maxLength).split(biiiigString);
```

**EDIT**: Splitter is from '*com.google.common.base.Splitter*'

But, since the splitting it for exactly 1400 characters would yield splitting at the middle of the lines and would make the split string meaningless to read. I want to match till the end of the line (i.e., till the next line break) where the 1400 characters match and then split the string.

I tried the below to check my luck,

```
Splitter.onPattern("(.|\\r\\n){1400}[^\\n]*\\n").split(biiiigString)
```

But, this cannot split as this cannot ignore the characters till last line break.

I googled few many times but could not get any. Though, i saw a switch statement like \K would ignore all the matched regexPatter before it, this is not supported by java.

I need a solution in java to get this thing working.

Comment: Do not use regex, Just take substrings.

Comment: Should you not peek at 1400th character after index `start` and check if the character is a char. If so, find the space _before_ that index `end`, and set `end` as new index. Then substring from store the partial string. Repeat this process with a new starting index: `start = end` until end of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have approached this using String's [`substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), [`lastIndexOf(str, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-) and [`charAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) method.

The `charAt(int)` is used to check if the character is a space or not. If it's not a space, check for a space *before* that index. This is achieved by `lastIndexOf(str, int)`. Then pick a substring from the starting index to that index. Repeat the process after that ending index until the end of string is reached.

As result, I come on this:

```
public List<String> splitBySize(String s, int length) {
    List<String> splits = new ArrayList();
    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = length;

        while (endIndex < s.length()) {
            if (s.charAt(endIndex) != ' ') {
                endIndex = s.lastIndexOf(' ', endIndex);
                // if endIndex <= startIndex -> strategy?
            }
            splits.add(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
            startIndex = endIndex;
            endIndex = startIndex + length;
        }
        // add last part
        splits.add(s.substring(startIndex));
    }
    return splits;
}
```

However, it has to be noted that there must be an additional check if there is no space in the substring between starting index and starting index + 1400 characters (see comment in code). It may be less likely, but please consider that situation. Either you break that string (thus resetting the `endIndex` back to `startIndex + length`) so that the substring is broken in two parts if there is no space.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This worked for me. I changed the ' ' with '\n' for line breaks. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is inbuilt functionality to do something like this.

Try to implement this algorithm...
1. Split string into array `lines` from end line character.
2. Make temporary string by appending strings from array & count length.
3. Repeat step 2 until length of the temporary string is greater then 1400.
4. Add the temporary string in the result array & repeat about steps for all the strings in `lines`.